# Порядок байт и направление адресации в C

Tags: c

Что такое порядок байтов - я понимаю. Но я совершенно не понимаю, как "правильно" представлять адресацию байтов в памяти компьютера. Я всегда считал, что правильное представление, это **слева-направо**, но теперь я в этом не уверен.

Например:

```
// Допустим, эта переменная лежит в памяти по адресу 2...
// И имеет порядок Little-Endian
uint16_t u16 = 256;
```

Тогда, получается, что:

```
Номер байта: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6...
Значение:    x x 0 1 x x x...
                 ^
                 &u16 вернет этот адрес
```

Это правильное представление?

Данную ситуацию можно представить еще и так:

```
Номер байта: ...6 5 4 3 2 1 0
Значение:    ...x x x 1 0 x x
                        ^
                        &u16 вернет этот адрес
```

И дальше мозг ломается...

В общем, вопросы такие:

1) Корректно ли представление о том, что адресация байтов памяти идет **слева-направо**? По крайней мере, при рассмотрении **C**.

2) Где описано, что конкретно возвращает оператор получения адреса объекта *&object*? Этот оператор возвращает адрес того байта объекта, который ближе всего к *началу координат*? Или что?

Comment: Это всё очень условно. В нашей культуре можно считать, что байты размещаются слева-направо и адрес объекта это адрес самого левого байта. Порядок байтов внутри целых чисел это совсем другое.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Корректно ли представление о том, что адресация байтов памяти идет слева-направо?

Разумеется - нет. В памяти НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ понятия "лево" и "право". В памяти есть только "адреса" от 0 до некоего максимума. Ваш вопрос просто не имеет смысла. Какого цвета электрон? Жёлтенький? Или зелёненький?

> 2) Где описано, что конкретно возвращает оператор получения адреса объекта &object?

Абсолютно во всех стандартах языка С написано, что оператор "&" возвращает АДРЕС. Вас интересует, как устроен этот самый АДРЕС? Надо смотреть даташит на конкретный процессор. Так как в разных процессорах адресация организована по разному. Единственное, что можно гарантировать: загрузка такого АДРЕСА на регистр индексации, при сложении с базовым адресом, даст верный адрес объекта в памяти процесса. Именно процесса, а не процессора, так как в понятие "адрес" ещё вмешивается диспетчер виртуальной памяти.

Короче, как в советские времена говорили пассажирам автобуса:

- Старик, оставь пустые бредни!
- Входи ты - с задней,
- Сходи - с передней!

  :-)

Это я к тому, что не зря в языке **запрещены** любые операции с адресами, кроме инкремента и вычитания двух адресов. А эти опреации разрешены только потому, что адрес жёстко связан с ТИПОМ на который он ссылается. Поэтому компилятор и может выполнить инкремент или вычислить разницу. Любые другие операции с указателями могут привести к самым неожиданным последствиям.

Comment: Можно ссылку на официальный источник, где говорится о том, что любые операции, кроме математики указателей, с указателями запрещены?

Comment: **Можно ссылку на официальный источник** - Вот эти авторы: "Брайан В. Керниган, Деннис М. Ритчи" - для Вас достаточно авторитетны? В разделе 5.4. своей библии они пишут: "Можно производить следующие операции с указателями: присваивание значения
указателя другому указателю того же типа, сложение и вычитание указателя и целого,
вычитание и сравнение двух указателей, указывающих на элементы одного и того же
массива, а также присваивание указателю нуля и сравнение указателя с нулем. **Других операций с указателями производить не допускается**."

Comment: Окей, а как же тогда миллиарды кода на C, в котором предполагается, что (1) адрес элементарного типа есть адрес его первого байта (2) адрес структуры есть адрес первого байта ее первого элемента (3) . Плюс, согласно Стандарту, компиляторам, запрещено менять порядок элементов структур, и это требование было введено не просто так, а потому, что весь существующий C код, а возможно и весь код C++, работает с расчетом на определенное расположение байтов в объектах элементарных типов, а так же структур, в определенном порядке. Единственное, что может влиять на интерпретацию данных, это порядок байт.

Comment: Например, тут тоже делают недопустимые операции?: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/au-endianc/

Comment: **тут тоже делают недопустимые операции?** Неплохо бы, прежде чем с таким жаром возражать, прочитать что пишут отцы-основатели ещё разок и сравнить с кодом :-) Вам не бросилось в глаза, что для работы с байтами используется массивы *char one[4];* и т.д.? А авторы языка пишут: *указывающих на элементы одного и того же массива*. Так в чём проблема?